# Symfony EventListener How does it exactly work

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to understand how to build a event Listener in Symfony and how it works.

so I have looked at the Example calss from Symfony Docs.

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/EventListener/AcmeExceptionListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class AcmeExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
// You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $message = sprintf(
            'My Error says: %s with code: %s',
            $exception->getMessage(),
            $exception->getCode()
        );

// Customize your response object to display the exception details
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($message);

// HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
// holds status code and header details
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

// Send the modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

I understand that `$event->getException()` from GetResponseForExceptionEvent class picks a Event throwns in my application

What i don't quiet understand is how does why `$exception` can use `getMessage()` `and getCode()`.
Can someone briefly explain these to me and Maybe a bit more about Symfony Event Listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a huge topic and I found it hard to understand when I was learning it via Symfony documentation and other online blogs. I will recommend you to view [this](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/event-subscriber) tutorial from KNP University and believe me you will have a very clear understanding of it.

Comment: I have to admit you are 100% right it is very hard for me to find well explained Documentation on Listeners for SYmfony. The link you sent me its truly amazing thank you. Answerd a lot of questions I had

Comment: Glad I could help :) believe me I was relieved to come across KNP too.

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with Symfony Events, when yo use `$event->getException` you are getting an instance of class [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), this class has those methods defined.

Comment: I agree with you and I know that but how do these link.

Answer (score 0):

The last question first.

> why `$exception` can use `getMessage()` and `getCode()`

Symfony is a framework that use strict Objcet Oriented paradigm. So oftenly a function:

- had an object type argument,
- return also an object
- and an object also can have it's own function and properties

In this example for simplicity we can think, `$exception` is an `Exception` object that have properties that can be see in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php).

Also to understands how listeners works, it help if you have some knowledge about "Observer Design Pattern". This is a litle explanation.

- there is an object called dispatcher (EventDispatcher)
- this object had an array contains many listeners object
- at point of time the kernel told dispatcher to dispatch
- and dispatcher told all of listener to execute functions if exists

And to understanding your code, you create a listeners that active **when** `Exception` is thrown from anywhere. So you can choose to or not to show your error message.